# wordpress add page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i am writing plugin for wordpress and in this plugin admin should add some information like this ===> title,text in database.

I want that this information to be added  as wordpress page in database.

What function should i use to make this task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_insert_post` for that http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Pages are just a type of posts in WP.

```
$post = array(
  'post_title' => 'my Title',
  'post_content' => 'my Text',
  'post_type' => 'page',

  'post_status' => 'publish',   
  'post_author' => 1
);

wp_insert_post( $post );
```

Comment: uh,i new this function just fought without trying that for page where would be other :). Thank you it helped me